# Which of these destructor calls are excecuted multiple times?

Tags: c++, destructor

I am learning C++ right now, coming from Java. I do know that I should use `vector`s instead of arrays, however I want to also understand the fundamentals.

I've written a struct that I want to access with double `[]`. That does work and it fulfills its purpose. However, when the destructor is called I get an error:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I asked a friend and he could not help me either.

Here is the struct:

```cpp
#pragma once
class BitArray2
{
public:

    int size;
    
    BitArray2();
    BitArray2(int size);

    ~BitArray2();

    bool** bits = nullptr;

    struct Row{
        public:
        int size;
        bool** bits_row = nullptr;
        int index;

        Row(int size, int index, bool** bits_row)
            :size(size), index(index), bits_row(bits_row){}


        ~Row(){
            bits_row = nullptr;
        }

        bool& operator[](int col_index);
    };

    Row** rows = nullptr;

    Row& operator[](int row_index);



};

BitArray2::BitArray2(){
    BitArray2(1);
}

BitArray2::BitArray2(int size)
    :size(size){
    bits = new bool*[size];
    rows = new Row*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        rows[i] = new Row(size, i, bits);
        bits[i] = new bool[size];
    }
    
}

BitArray2::~BitArray2(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] rows[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] bits[i];
    }
    delete[] rows;
    delete[] bits;
}

bool& BitArray2::Row::operator[](const int col_index)
{
    if(col_index < size){
        return bits_row[index][col_index];
    }
    else{
        return bits_row[0][0];
    }
}

BitArray2::Row& BitArray2::operator[](int row_index)
{
    if(row_index < size){
        return  *rows[row_index];
    }
    else{
        return *rows[0];
    }
}
```

And I will also give you an example application:

```cpp
BitArray2 b(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = (j+i)%2 == 0?true:false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(b[i][j]){
                std::cout << 1;
            }else{
                std::cout << 0;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

which outputs:

```
1010
0101
1010
0101
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So I would guess, that my destructor is not correct. In my mind, I somewhere try to delete an object that was already deleted by a different destructor before. With me deleting the `rows` first, which hold reference to the `bits` pointer, I set the pointer to `nullptr`, I order for the destructor to not delete the top `bits` pointer array. Maybe this does not work, because the pointer inside the `rows` struct is the same as in the general `BitArray2` struct.

I would love some more information on what the issue is, or some source that I could study to understand the issue that I am having.

Comment: `BitArray2(1);` doesn't call that constructor for `this`. It makes a temporary `BitArray2` inside of the constructor. You need to put the delegate constructor in the initialize list like `BitArray2::BitArray2() : BitArray2(1) {}`

Comment: Unless it's a requirement for your assignment, don't use pointers and explicit dynamic allocation. For dynamic arrays use `std::vector`.

Comment: And you don't follow [the rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You need to do that if you ever pass or return the `BitArray2` objects by value.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `(j+i)%2 == 0?true:false` is far more verbose than it needs to be. `(j+i)%2 == 0` does exactly the same thing. Also, that `if` statement that shows the values isn’t needed; `std::cout << b[i][j]` does the same thing. And, finally, this code doesn’t need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: If possible, print some text in the destructors.  This should give you an example of the execution story.

Comment: *In my mind I somewhere try to delete an object that was already deleted by a different deconstuctor before* -- First the term is `destructor`, not `deconstructor`.  Second, you should be printing the value of `this` in your destructor instead of guessing which object is being deleted.  Last, you should be using working examples as a guide, instead of trying to learn C++ by trial and error.  Your code has too many errors.  If you insist on not using vectors, [here is a 2d array class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).

Comment: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/4zsoqnb11)

Comment: `rows[i] = new Row(size, i, bits);` creates a single object, not an array, so later on must be freed with `delete` and not `delete[]`. Even better, reconsider using an array of pointers here, and just use an array of `Row` objects instead. (This is an option which is not present in Java)

Comment: "`Row** rows = nullptr`" - don't use raw pointers and especially not raw double pointers.

Comment: Use of `new` and `delete` operators is at this point advanced C++, not fundamental. Understanding them is useful for maintaining older code and interfacing with older code that needs them, but they should otherwise almost never appear in brand new code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Outstanding [example](https://godbolt.org/z/4zsoqnb11). I learned a couple of tricks. The only thing I might do differently is to make sure that `m_rows` and `m_cols` were set to zero in moved-from objects. In addition, I would probably use `std::size_t` instead of `unsigned`, but that's a small detail. In my projects, I never see arrays with billions of elements anyway.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I appreciate the insights. @PaulMcKenzie great example.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Nice example. Note however that `new T[nrows*ncols]{ val };` initializes only the `[0]` element with `val`, leaving the rest default-initialized. (Or at least that's what happens in my experiment, where I see the copy ctor being called once, and the `T()` ctor being called many times.) I don't know how to fix that in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Patching up `BitArray2` as defined in the original post

Most of the problems were identified in the comments:

1. Delegating constructor needs to be part of base-member initialization.
2. Class `BitArray2` needs to use the "Rule of Three" or the "Rule of Five".
3. Unnecessarily complicated function `main`.
4. Destructor incorrectly used `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

The fixes are marked in the code below, along with comments that give some additional detail. Look for `#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1`.

I also identified a some other things that need fixing:

5. Subscripting operators will fail when `size` is zero. Fixed by adding check in constructor.
6. A subtle memory leak is possible. See my notes in the constructor.
7. Whenever I code `operator=`, I automatically code a `const` version to go with it. I have done that here.
8. The struct `Row` does not need a destructor. It does not use operator `new`. Therefore, it should not use operator `delete`. It is a "Rule of Zero" struct.

@PaulMcKenzie linked to an [outstanding example](https://godbolt.org/z/4zsoqnb11) that shows how to properly code a dynamically allocated, two-dimensional array. His code deserves study.

```cpp
// BitArray2.h
#pragma once
#define FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE 1
class BitArray2
{
public:

    int size;

    BitArray2();
    BitArray2(int size);

    ~BitArray2();

#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
    // Class BitArray2 follows the "Rule of Three", 
    // or, possibly, the "Rule of Five". Either way, 
    // I have deleted the copy constructor and 
    // copy-assignment operator, so that they cannot 
    // be invoked. If you need them, you will need to 
    // code "deep-copy" versions of each.
    BitArray2(BitArray2 const&) = delete;
    BitArray2& operator=(BitArray2 const&) = delete;
#endif

    bool** bits = nullptr;

    struct Row {
    public:
        int size;
        bool** bits_row = nullptr;
        int index;

        Row(int size, int index, bool** bits_row)
            : size(size), index(index), bits_row(bits_row)
        {}

#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
        // Struct Row follows the "Rule of Zero".
        // Nothing was allocated with operator new,
        // so nothing gets deleted. Under the "Rule 
        // of Zero" there is no need for a destructor.
#else
        ~Row() {
            bits_row = nullptr;
        }
#endif

        bool& operator[](int col_index);
#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
        // Support for constant objects
        bool const& operator[](int col_index) const;
#endif
    };

    Row** rows = nullptr;

    Row& operator[](int row_index);
#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
    // Support for constant objects
    Row const& operator[](int row_index) const;
#endif

};
// end file: BitArray2.h
```

```cpp
// BitArray2.cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include "BitArray2.h"

#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
// Fix delegating constructor.
BitArray2::BitArray2() 
    : BitArray2(1)
{}
#else
BitArray2::BitArray2() {
    BitArray2(1);
}
#endif

BitArray2::BitArray2(int size)
    : size(size)
{
#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
    // The implementation of operator[] requires a non-zero size.
    if (size < 1)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid size");

    // Possible memory leak
    // If the ctor fails, and throws std::bad_alloc, 
    // the dtor will NOT be called. When that happens, 
    // any allocations that DID WORK need to be deleted 
    // here. I have not coded a fix for this.
#endif

    bits = new bool* [size];
    rows = new Row * [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        rows[i] = new Row(size, i, bits);
        bits[i] = new bool[size];
    }
}

BitArray2::~BitArray2() {
#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
    // Changed `delete[]` to `delete`.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete rows[i];
        delete[] bits[i];
    }
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] rows[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] bits[i];
    }
#endif
    delete[] rows;
    delete[] bits;
}

bool& BitArray2::Row::operator[](const int col_index)
{
    if (col_index < size) {
        return bits_row[index][col_index];
    }
    else {
        return bits_row[0][0];
    }
}
#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
// Support for constant objects
bool const&
BitArray2::Row::operator[](const int col_index) const
{
    if (col_index < size) {
        return bits_row[index][col_index];
    }
    else {
        return bits_row[0][0];
    }
}
#endif
BitArray2::Row& BitArray2::operator[](int row_index)
{
    if (row_index < size) {
        return *rows[row_index];
    }
    else {
        return *rows[0];
    }
}
#if FIX_BY_TBXFREEWARE == 1
// Support for constant objects
BitArray2::Row const&
BitArray2::operator[](int row_index) const
{
    if (row_index < size) {
        return *rows[row_index];
    }
    else {
        return *rows[0];
    }
}
#endif
// end file: BitArray2.cpp
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "BitArray2.h"
int main()
{
    BitArray2 b(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            b[i][j] = (j + i) % 2 == 0 ? true : false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (b[i][j])
                std::cout << 1;
            else
                std::cout << 0;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
1010
0101
1010
0101
```

Comment: Thank you! This was great, I’ve taken away a lot. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

##### Writing `BitArray2` from scratch

The following class is probably what you were imagining when you began writing `BitArray2`.

It follows the "Rule of 4 (and a half)," a name used by Arthur O'Dwyer in his [talk at CppCon 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ&t=37m32s). You get the "half" because the copy-assignment operator and the move-assignment operator have been combined in the same function.

```cpp
        BitArray2& operator= (BitArray2 that) noexcept
        {
            swap(that);
            return *this;
        }
        void swap(BitArray2& that) noexcept
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(this->data_ptr, that.data_ptr);
            swap(this->row_ptr, that.row_ptr);
            swap(this->n_rows_, that.n_rows_);
            swap(this->n_cols_, that.n_cols_);
        }
        friend void swap(BitArray2& a, BitArray2& b) noexcept
        {
            a.swap(b);
        }
```

This is is the *copy-and-swap* algorithm. When the compiler copies the argument into the value parameter, it will choose the move constructor for rvalue arguments, and the copy constructor for lvalues.

This implementation of `BitArray2` does not require an array to be square. I added a new constructor, `BitArray2(n_rows, n_cols)`, so that you can have arrays with differing numbers of rows and columns. It shares function `allocate_memory` with the copy constructor. That's where all the fun happens.

In order to make the class more general, I introduced type alias `value_type` as a synonym for `bool`, and also renamed member variable `bits` to `data_ptr`. If you want to have an array of some different value type in the future, all you have to do is change the definition of `value_type`.

At the same time, I changed the name of member variable `rows` to `row_ptr`. That name mirrors the name given to `data_ptr`. Both are pointers to pointers.

```cpp
    public:
        using value_type = bool;
        using size_type = std::size_t;

    private:
        // Instance variables
        value_type** data_ptr{ nullptr };
        Row** row_ptr{ nullptr };
        size_type n_rows_{}, n_cols_{};
```

Subscripts no longer have type `int`; now they use `size_type`, which is an alias for `std::size_t`.

A pair of "getter" functions return the number of rows and columns in a `BitArray2`.

```cpp
        size_type n_rows() const noexcept
        {
            return n_rows_;
        }
        size_type n_cols() const noexcept
        {
            return n_cols_;
        }
```

##### Memory allocation

Every time you use operator `new`, there is chance that memory allocation will fail. Operator `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc` object when that happens. That can be trouble if the throw happens inside a constructor.

An object's destructor function cannot be called until after the object has been completely constructed, i.e., after its constructor has finished running. So, if the constructor throws an exception, the `delete` operations that are normally executed by the destructor will not be run. You have to do them manually, inside the constructor.

That means that every call to operator `new` in a constructor, except perhaps the first, must be enclosed within a try/catch block. When a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, you must catch it, and manually deallocate, i.e., delete, any allocations that were made before the exception was thrown. Given the design of `BitArray2`, there could be a lot of them!

Function `allocate_memory` uses a couple of helper functions, `deallocate_data_ptr` and `deallocate_row_ptr`, to handle the deletions.

```cpp
        void deallocate_data_ptr(size_type row) noexcept
        {
            while (row--)
                delete[] data_ptr[row];
            delete data_ptr;
            data_ptr = nullptr;
        }
        void deallocate_row_ptr(size_type row) noexcept
        {
            while (row--)
                delete row_ptr[row];
            delete row_ptr;
            row_ptr = nullptr;
        }
```

These helper functions do double duty, because they are also called from the destructor.

```cpp
        ~BitArray2() noexcept
        {
            if (row_ptr)
                deallocate_row_ptr(n_rows_);
            if (data_ptr)
                deallocate_data_ptr(n_rows_);
        }
```

When called from the destructor, the helper functions delete all rows (because the argument is `n_rows_`), but when they are called from `allocate_memory`, they only delete rows above the row that triggered the `std::bad_alloc`. Thus, they are called with argument `row`, rather than `n_rows_`.

Here is function `allocate_memory`:

```cpp
        void allocate_memory()
        {
            // The first call to operator `new` is free. If it throws 
            // a `std::bad_alloc`, we do not need to catch it. Since 
            // nothing will have been allocated, there is nothing that 
            // needs to be deallocated.
            data_ptr = new value_type* [n_rows_];

            // Every subsequent call to `new` must occur in a try/catch 
            // block. If `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc`, we must catch 
            // it, and deallocate all previously allocated memory.
            for (size_type row{}; row < n_rows_; ++row)
            {
                try { data_ptr[row] = new value_type[n_cols_]{}; }
                catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { deallocate_data_ptr(row); throw; }
            }

            try { row_ptr = new Row* [n_rows_]; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { deallocate_data_ptr(n_rows_); throw; }

            for (size_type row{}; row < n_rows_; ++row)
            {
                try { row_ptr[row] = new Row{ n_cols_, row, data_ptr }; }
                catch (std::bad_alloc const&)
                {
                    deallocate_row_ptr(row);
                    deallocate_data_ptr(n_rows_);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Function `allocate_memory` is called from the main constructor, as well as from the copy constructor. In the main constructor, I am now allowing arrays with zero rows and zero columns, but only if both are zero. There is, of course, not much you can do with an empty array, but you can replace such an array via assignment from another array.

```cpp
        explicit BitArray2(
            size_type const n_rows,
            size_type const n_cols)
            : data_ptr{ nullptr }
            , row_ptr{ nullptr }
            , n_rows_{ n_rows }
            , n_cols_{ n_cols }
        {
            if (n_rows && n_cols)
                allocate_memory();
            else if (!n_rows && n_cols)
                throw std::invalid_argument("BitArray2: number of rows is 0");
            else if (n_rows && !n_cols)
                throw std::invalid_argument("BitArray2: number of columns is 0");
        }

        BitArray2(BitArray2 const& that)
            : data_ptr{ nullptr }
            , row_ptr{ nullptr }
            , n_rows_{ that.n_rows_ }
            , n_cols_{ that.n_cols_ }
        {
            if (that.data_ptr)
            {
                allocate_memory();
                for (size_type row{}; row < n_rows_; ++row)
                    std::copy(
                        &that.data_ptr[row][zero],
                        &that.data_ptr[row][n_cols_],
                        &this->data_ptr[row][zero]);
            }
        }
```

##### Subscripting with `operator[]` and class `Row`

Subscripting is one of the most elegant features of the original `BitArray2` class. The clever use of class `Row` to provide a second `operator[]` function (for columns) is something I had not seen before.

In this implementation of `BitArray2`, very little has changed. The biggest difference is that it no longer resolves subscripting errors by returning the first element of the array. Instead, it throws a `std::out_of_range` exception.

```cpp
    public:
        Row& operator[](size_type const row_index)
        {
            check_row_subscript(row_index);
            return *row_ptr[row_index];
        }
        Row const& operator[](size_type const row_index) const
        {
            check_row_subscript(row_index);
            return *row_ptr[row_index];
        }

    private:
        void check_row_subscript(const size_type row) const
        {
            if (n_rows_ <= row)
                throw std::out_of_range("BitArray2: Row index is out of range.");
        }
```

In addition, I changed struct `Row` into a proper class.

```cpp
        class Row
        {
            // Class `Row` adds a bit of syntatic sugar.
            // Its `operator[]` will become the second subscript 
            // for a `BitArray2` object, i.e, it will be the column
            // subscript.
            size_type n_cols_in_row{};         // a copy of `n_cols_`
            size_type index{};                 // row subscript of `this` row
            value_type** data_row{ nullptr };  // a copy of `data_ptr`
        public:
            Row(
                size_type const n_cols_in_row,
                size_type const index,
                value_type** const data_row)
                : n_cols_in_row{ n_cols_in_row }
                , index{ index }
                , data_row{ data_row }
            {}
            value_type& operator[] (size_type const col_index)
            {
                check_column_subscript(col_index);
                return data_row[index][col_index];
            }
            value_type const& operator[] (size_type const col_index) const
            {
                check_column_subscript(col_index);
                return data_row[index][col_index];
            }
        private:
            void check_column_subscript(size_type const col) const
            {
                if (n_cols_in_row <= col)
                    throw std::out_of_range("BitArray2: Column index is out of range.");
            }
        };
```

##### The complete class `BitArray2`

Aside from the move constructor, and two other constructors, the only function we have not yet seen is the equality operator. You will find that, along with everything else, in the complete source code below.

This implementation handles all the test cases in the original post with ease.

```cpp
// BitArray2.h
#ifndef BITARRAY2_H
#define BITARRAY2_H

#include <algorithm>  // copy, equal, swap
#include <cstddef>    // size_t
#include <new>        // bad_alloc
#include <stdexcept>  // invalid_argument, out_of_range
#include <utility>    // exchange

class BitArray2
{
    // The `BitArray2` class in the OP is a square, two-
    // dimensional array of `bools`. The number of rows and 
    // the number of columns are both equal to argument `size` 
    // in the constructor.
    // 
    // In this implementation, `BitArray2` is a rectangular 
    // array, where the number rows, `n_rows_`, does not have 
    // to be the same as the number of columns, `n_cols_`.
    // 
    // Rather than hard-code type `bool` into the code, we use 
    // type alias `value_type`, which is an alias for `bool`. 
    // 
    // It the future, it should be relatively easy to change 
    // `BitArray2` into a class template that handles other 
    // value types.
public:
    using value_type = bool;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

private:
    class Row
    {
        // Class `Row` adds a bit of syntatic sugar.
        // Its `operator[]` will become the second subscript 
        // for a `BitArray2` object, i.e, it will be the column
        // subscript.
        size_type n_cols_in_row{};         // a copy of `n_cols_`
        size_type index{};                 // row subscript of `this` row
        value_type** data_row{ nullptr };  // a copy of `data_ptr`
    public:
        Row(
            size_type const n_cols_in_row,
            size_type const index,
            value_type** const data_row)
            : n_cols_in_row{ n_cols_in_row }
            , index{ index }
            , data_row{ data_row }
        {}
        value_type& operator[] (size_type const col_index)
        {
            check_column_subscript(col_index);
            return data_row[index][col_index];
        }
        value_type const& operator[] (size_type const col_index) const
        {
            check_column_subscript(col_index);
            return data_row[index][col_index];
        }
    private:
        void check_column_subscript(size_type const col) const
        {
            if (n_cols_in_row <= col)
                throw std::out_of_range("BitArray2: Column index is out of range.");
        }
    };

    // Instance variables
    value_type** data_ptr{ nullptr };
    Row** row_ptr{ nullptr };
    size_type n_rows_{}, n_cols_{};
    enum : size_type { zero, one };

public:
    // Constructors
    BitArray2()
        : BitArray2{ one, one }
    {}
    explicit BitArray2(size_type const size)
        : BitArray2{ size, size }
    {}
    explicit BitArray2(
        size_type const n_rows,
        size_type const n_cols)
        : data_ptr{ nullptr }
        , row_ptr{ nullptr }
        , n_rows_{ n_rows }
        , n_cols_{ n_cols }
    {
        if (n_rows && n_cols)
            allocate_memory();
        else if (!n_rows && n_cols)
            throw std::invalid_argument("BitArray2: number of rows is 0");
        else if (n_rows && !n_cols)
            throw std::invalid_argument("BitArray2: number of columns is 0");
    }

    // "Rule of Four (and a half)" (plus a noexcept swap function)
    //   1. destructor
    //   2. copy constructor
    //   3. move constructor
    //   4. copy-assignment operator
    //   4.5. move-assignment operator (handled by copy-and-swap assignment)
    //   5. `swap` used to implement assignment operators

    ~BitArray2() noexcept
    {
        if (row_ptr)
            deallocate_row_ptr(n_rows_);
        if (data_ptr)
            deallocate_data_ptr(n_rows_);
    }
    BitArray2(BitArray2 const& that)
        : data_ptr{ nullptr }
        , row_ptr{ nullptr }
        , n_rows_{ that.n_rows_ }
        , n_cols_{ that.n_cols_ }
    {
        if (that.data_ptr)
        {
            allocate_memory();
            for (size_type row{}; row < n_rows_; ++row)
                std::copy(
                    &that.data_ptr[row][zero],
                    &that.data_ptr[row][n_cols_],
                    &this->data_ptr[row][zero]);
        }
    }
    BitArray2(BitArray2&& that) noexcept
        : data_ptr{ std::exchange(that.data_ptr, nullptr) }
        , row_ptr{ std::exchange(that.row_ptr, nullptr) }
        , n_rows_{ std::exchange(that.n_rows_, zero) }
        , n_cols_{ std::exchange(that.n_cols_, zero) }
    {}
    BitArray2& operator= (BitArray2 that) noexcept
    {
        swap(that);
        return *this;
    }
    void swap(BitArray2& that) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(this->data_ptr, that.data_ptr);
        swap(this->row_ptr, that.row_ptr);
        swap(this->n_rows_, that.n_rows_);
        swap(this->n_cols_, that.n_cols_);
    }
    friend void swap(BitArray2& a, BitArray2& b) noexcept
    {
        a.swap(b);
    }

    // Subscripting operators
    Row& operator[](size_type const row_index)
    {
        check_row_subscript(row_index);
        return *row_ptr[row_index];
    }
    Row const& operator[](size_type const row_index) const
    {
        check_row_subscript(row_index);
        return *row_ptr[row_index];
    }

    // "Getter" functions
    size_type n_rows() const noexcept
    {
        return n_rows_;
    }
    size_type n_cols() const noexcept
    {
        return n_cols_;
    }

    // Equality operator
    bool operator== (BitArray2 const& that) const
    {
        if (this->n_rows_ != that.n_rows_ ||
            this->n_cols_ != that.n_cols_)
            return false;
        for (size_type row{}; row < this->n_rows_; ++row)
            if (!std::equal(
                &this->data_ptr[row][zero],
                &this->data_ptr[row][this->n_cols_],
                &that.data_ptr[row][zero])
                )
                return false;
        return true;
    }
private:
    void allocate_memory()
    {
        // The first call to operator `new` is free. If it throws 
        // a `std::bad_alloc`, we do not need to catch it. Since 
        // nothing will have been allocated, there is nothing that 
        // needs to be deallocated.
        data_ptr = new value_type* [n_rows_];

        // Every subsequent call to `new` must occur in a try/catch 
        // block. If `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc`, we must catch 
        // it, and deallocate all previously allocated memory.
        for (size_type row{}; row < n_rows_; ++row)
        {
            try { data_ptr[row] = new value_type[n_cols_]{}; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { deallocate_data_ptr(row); throw; }
        }

        try { row_ptr = new Row* [n_rows_]; }
        catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { deallocate_data_ptr(n_rows_); throw; }

        for (size_type row{}; row < n_rows_; ++row)
        {
            try { row_ptr[row] = new Row{ n_cols_, row, data_ptr }; }
            catch (std::bad_alloc const&)
            {
                deallocate_row_ptr(row);
                deallocate_data_ptr(n_rows_);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    void check_row_subscript(const size_type row) const
    {
        if (n_rows_ <= row)
            throw std::out_of_range("BitArray2: Row index is out of range.");
    }
    void deallocate_data_ptr(size_type row) noexcept
    {
        while (row--)
            delete[] data_ptr[row];
        delete data_ptr;
        data_ptr = nullptr;
    }
    void deallocate_row_ptr(size_type row) noexcept
    {
        while (row--)
            delete row_ptr[row];
        delete row_ptr;
        row_ptr = nullptr;
    }
};
#endif  // !BITARRAY2_H
// end file: BitArray2.h
```